# Не могу найти ошибку в работе с массивом

Tags: массивы, objective-c

```
 - (void)reorderPartners {
if (!self.cardsArray || !self.cardsArray.count) {
    return;
}

NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *oldArray = [self.cardsArray mutableCopy];

int partnersToFind = 1;
int index = 0;
while (partnersToFind) {
    NSString* brand = ((Card*)oldArray[index]).company.brand;
    if ([brand isEqualToString:@"smth"]) {
        [newArray addObject:oldArray[index]];
        [oldArray removeObject:oldArray[index]];
        partnersToFind--;
        index--;
    }
    index++;
}
partnersToFind = 2;
index = 0;

while (partnersToFind) {
    NSString *brand = ((Card*)oldArray[index]).company.brand;
    if ([brand isEqualToString:@"smth"] || [brand isEqualToString:@"smth"]) {
        [newArray addObject:oldArray[index]];
        [oldArray removeObject:oldArray[index]];
        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)oldArray.count);
        partnersToFind--;
        index--;

    }

  index++;
}

for (Card* card in oldArray) {
    NSString* brand = card.company.brand;
    if (![brand isEqualToString:@"smth"]) {
        [newArray addObject:card];
    }
}


self.cardsArray = [newArray copy];
```

}
При сборке прилетает такая ошибка:
-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'.
Я понимаю что это связано с пустым массивом. Но после 10 часов дебага мало что соображаю.Не пинайте сильно, помогите разобраться.

Comment: Сделайте проверку прежде чем брать значения с пустого массива.

Comment: @OrestMykha, вы имеете ввиду код типа if array.isEmpty(...) то брать значения?

Comment: @OrestMykha, докопался таки. Оказалось что массив пустой, потому что ссылается на другой массив. Который,в свою очередь, ссылается на entity в Core Data.
О чем красноречиво говорит:
 "<NSManagedObject: 0x7a7b1cf0> (entity: Card; id: 0x7b970340 <x-coredata://C2D5D0A5-2D4E-48FB-B0B4-F8C928BFD2AA/Card/p4> ; data: <fault>)"
Попал я передрягу))
Спасибо Вам за ценный совет!

Comment: Рад был помочь, Удачи!